# How to get the installation directory (installed with MSI, created with VS2010) at a custom uninstall action?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

So I've created a simple msi-setup for my application using a setup project and added a couple of custom actions that take care of stuff like extracting files from archives. Now, there are two extra files in my program files -directory which means that the MSI won't remove the directory at the uninstall by itself. My solution to this was to create a custom action that removes the rest of the files.

Now this works just fine and dandy, as long as the default directory is used at installation. But what if the user chooses to change it? I'd assume there has to be a very simple way to read the directory at the custom action, but I'm not quite sure what that is.

As far as I've found out by googling, there are properties such as TARGETDIR related to the MSI-package. However, some sites also say that I should be setting this property by myself, at the installation stage.

All this has left me quite confused. Basically I see two ways to resolve this:

1) Make sure the application does not create files by itself, and the MSI will take care of it. This would mean a bit more work because I'm not responsible for those extra files.

2) Find out the installation directory at the custom action while uninstalling the application, and remove the last bits by myself. This is the quick-and-dirty way as I see it, and would definitely suffice for now. But how to accomplish this?

Also while I'm here I might as well ask this one more related question. As I mentioned earlier, I extract some files at the install. Now, I'd like to get rid of these archives once I've extracted them. The problem is, if I do this, MSI will think my installation is broken and copy them back each time I launch the application. So how to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you need archives? Put all your files into MSI directly: it will handle both unpacking (installing) files and removing (uninstalling). And no need for custom actions.

Comment: I need archives because of the amount of files needed, which is in the tens of thousands.

Comment: Why do you think MSI can't handle them natively?

Comment: Because even adding all those files would be excruciatingly painful, and take hours. I don't even dare thinking of the time building the installer if I actually had added them all directly into the installer.

Comment: If you would add those files natively, you will also run into problems because there is a soft limit for the number of components per feature. Ref: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1043.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a custom action to remove the files. MSI has built in support for this scenario in two steps:

1. Use a search to locate the files you want to remove. Here is a tutorial
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371564(VS.85).aspx
2. Then you can schedule a file removal operation to actually delete the files.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371201(VS.85).aspx

Regarding your second question:

Don't add the archives to the File table. Instead create some self extracting archives and use  binary custom actions to unpack them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368085(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Ok so it's been a little while and I haven't had the time to actually implement this. Now that I do, I'm not quite sure what do you mean with not adding the archives to the file table. Thing is, I already use self-extracting archives which I run at the installation, but how can I actually bundle the files into my MSI installer without adding them to the file table?